# How to replace the special character and space with particular symbol in Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm developing windows phone 8 application.

I need to replace the special character,space,and multiple space into **-**  [dash symbol]

*sample*

with out replace string - **Hampton Inn & Suites Tampa East (Casino Area)**

I need like this        -   **Hampton-Inn-Suites-Tampa-East-Casino-Area**

I tried with regex like this

C#

```
 string passvalue = Regex.Replace(name, @"[ '&().,/]", "-");
```

Above code output

**Hampton-Inn---Suites-Tampa-East--Casino-Area-**

But i need **Hampton-Inn-Suites-Tampa-East-Casino-Area**

I need to remove
1.(Inn---Suites) Into (Inn-Suites)

2.(--Casino-Area) Into (-Casino-Area)

3.I don't need - at last (Area-) into (Area)

Thank you

Comment: Just add a `+` for "one or more" occurrence rather than for "one" occurrence as you have now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add a `+` quantifier after your character class `[]` to remove multiple occurrence. After that do a `Trim` for hyphen to remove leading or trailing.

```
string passvalue = Regex.Replace(name, @"[ '&().,/]+", "-").Trim('-');
                                                   ^ added
```

But, I'll suggest to use regex `[^a-zA-Z]+` for your case:

```
string passvalue = Regex.Replace(name, @"[^a-zA-Z]+", "-").Trim('-');
```

Comment: Your suggest [^a-zA-Z]+ is working correctly my method is not show the correct result for some other values.

Comment: 2 is removed but i need it.
example
without replace string H2O Hilton Pensacola Beach 
With replace HO-Hilton-Pensacola-Beach
But I need H2O-Hilton-Pensacola-Beach

Comment: That case just do it like this `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

`'([^\w]+)'`

and replace with:

`'-'`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/wU9bB4

Comment: I try with your above regex like this string passvalue = Regex.Replace(name, @"([^\w]+)", "-");

Comment: @Gurunathan, Yes I saw that. Maybe, you can remove the last char